# C# Console numbered list unsure how to call index of an item in a list

Tags: c#

I cant get a numbered list working for my code, I want it to look like this:
1 - Fish
2 - Beans
3 - Car

```
inventoryList.Add"Fish";
inventoryList.Add"Beans";
inventoryList.Add"Car";
foreach (string item in inventoryList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((item.IndexOf(item) + 1) + " - " + item);

        }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Just use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: This code is not compiling, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `IndexOf` method on the list of string.

```
Console.WriteLine((inventoryList.IndexOf(item) + 1) + " - " + item);
```

Since you simply want a counter to be printed for the items in the list, you may avoid the `IndexOf` call on the list and simply replace it with a local counter variable. `IndexOf` method has to check each character in your string item with each character in each item in list, hence doing doing a possible **n*m** complex operation

```
var counter = 0;
foreach (string item in inventoryList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(++counter + " - " + item);
}
```

Comment: This has a `O(n*n)` complexity. Not a good idea for large lists.

Comment: @Dai Agree. A simple counter is good enough

Comment: @Shyju thanks so much! Totally helped so much for a school assignment!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `IndexOf` because it runs in `O(n)` time, so within a list iteration it will be of the order-of-`O(n*n)` which is bad.

You need to keep track of the item number as you iterate through the list. `foreach` is not like `for` in that there's no implicit index.

You can use Linq's `.Select( item, index )` overload, or keep track of it yourself:

```
foreach( var pair in inventoryList.Select( (e,i) => new { Index = i, Value = e } )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} - {1}", pair.Index + 1, pair.Value );
}
```

Or:

```
Int32 index = 0;
foreach( String item in inventoryList )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} - {1}", index + 1, item );
    index++;
}
```

Or:

```
for( Int32 i = 0; i < inventoryList.Count; i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} - {1}", i + 1, inventoryList[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using indexOf on list not a good option, try this way.

> IndexOf method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an
>   O(n) operation, where n is number of elements.

```
inventoryList.Add"Fish"; inventoryList.Add"Beans"; inventoryList.Add"Car"; 
                var index = 1;
                foreach (string item in inventoryList) { 
                Console.WriteLine(index + " - " + item); 
        index++;
                }
                 Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Linq:

```
inventoryList.Select((item, index) => new { Index = index, Name = item })
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(it =>
                      {
                         Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", it.Index + 1, it.Name);
                      });
```